# Java Executor implementation that expands before prior to add blocklist

Tags: java, multithreading

Back in the 90s when java was starting to be develloped machines hadn't even half a tenth resources they have today... multi thread was a "concept" and hardware limitations were the main concern the main focus in every step of software development

The interface Executor and all its main known implementations come from the early 2000s and were designed in with that mindset

BUT THE THINGS HAVE CHANGED [A LOT]

Everytime I want to use an Executor I face the problem...
Lets say:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 10, 60L, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue(20));
```

This statement will create a pool with 3 'always on' threads, a maximum active thread of 10 and a waiting list of 20

But its implementation is something like

if core pool has space
add
else if waiting list has space
addToWaitingList
else if has space to expand thread pool
add

This way if the core pool is full the executor will add the new tasks to the waiting list before even trying to expand the core pool...

For todays application this aproach is not ideal (not to say useless)

Java has been updated hundreds of times sime 2000 to today but I still dont know any OFFICIAL implementation of Executor that has the behavior -> expand pool before add to waiting list

IS THERE ANY IMPLEMENTATION THAT DOES THAT (WITHOUT IMPORTING A WHOLE API JUST FOR THIS)?

HOW CAN I CREATE A CLASS THAT HAS THIS BEHAVIOR ?

Comment: Are you aware of the `Executors ` factory methods?

Comment: I do, they facilitate by having easily understandable names but at bottom they do invoke one constructor like this.

Comment: Yeah but for example `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`"creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue", and `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` "creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, so that sounds like it addresses both your issues?

Comment: they dont even get close to my problem, if you read carefully and you understand how these executors work you will see that is far from being a solution... btw i already solved on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my way through

```
public class ThreadPoolExpandableExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {


    public ThreadPoolExpandableExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit) {
        this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());
    }

    public ThreadPoolExpandableExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, new InternalLinkedBlockingQueue(), threadFactory);
        this.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new InternalRejectedExecutionHandler(this.getQueue()));
    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void execute(Runnable command) {
        super.execute(command);
    };

    @Override
    public synchronized <T extends Object> java.util.concurrent.Future<T> submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(task);
    };

    private static final class InternalRejectedExecutionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {

        private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue;

        private InternalRejectedExecutionHandler(BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            try {
                this.queue.put(r);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private static final class InternalLinkedBlockingQueue extends LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private InternalLinkedBlockingQueue() {
            super(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean offer(Runnable e) {

            return false;
        }

    }
```

this class will have a corepoolsize always on
if new task is submited while corepool is full but maxpool has space a new thread will be created and started immediatally
if a new task is submited while corepool is full and maxpool is full, it will be added to the task queue

the solution is far from elegant, i created a queue implementation that always reject new items
but let them pushed inside with the put method

it only works if you (like me) doesnt care of having a infinite task queue

Answer (score 1):

For the standard **ThreadPoolExecutor** you can set:

- **corePoolSize** to ***maximal*** number of expected threads
- **maxPoolSize**  to the same value
- **keepAliveTime** and **unit** to reasonable value

and then to call ***allowsCoreThreadTimeOut​(true)*** before actual task scheduling.

As result, pool expansion will be preferred to the adding of task to waiting list.

The only side effect is that core workers will also finish after expiration of **keepAliveTime**. But this effect could be minimized by selection of reasonable value for this parameter.